# My search controller is not receiving any response

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?
    var resultView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))

        subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
        view.addSubview(subView)
        view.
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }
}
```

When I click my search bar, it is not working, it is frozen.

Comment: Is your searchBar in navigation bar?

Comment: no@AbhishekJadhav

Comment: don't create subview add directly searchBar in a view

Comment: when i drag and drop search bar its showing in interface but it not showing in simulator@AbhishekJadhav